# Spring security in JSP - click on not allowed action

Tags: jsp, click, spring-security

If user clicks on an action in namespace which role user hasn't now nothing happens. Can I intercept this and redirect him to some exception?

Example:

```
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/project/**" access="ROLE_PROJECT"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/statistics/**" access="ROLE_STATISTICS"/>
```

User has only one role - ROLE_PROJECT. And the developer (not me, of course :)) will forget to hide an action in /secure/statistics, so also this user will see it. How to handle the click on this action with some custom result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your use case and how to handle it is documented [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-web-filters.html#access-denied-handler) - `AccessDeniedHandler`